# Is it possible to get column name (header) in SQLite using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

Is it possible to get column names(Header) if table and columns are generated code'behind in sqlite?

tried this but it fail:

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();

string sSQL = "Select * from tblUser Where username = '" + txtUsername.Text + "'";
cmd.CommandText = sSQL;
cmd.Connection = clsCon.con;
SQLiteDataReader dr2;
dr2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
string columnName = dr2.GetName(1);
dr2.Read();

if (dr2.HasRows)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Username Already Exist!", "SQLite Test Application", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    txtUsername.Focus();
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**:  Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection) attacks.  To be clear, you want the names of the rows and columns?  It doesn't look like that is what you are retrieving in the code above.

Comment: @Brian yes i just want to get all columns names for each i generate a table.

Comment: DB Access code (in the code behind, of course), followed by `MessageBox` followed by `txtUsername.Focus();`. EPIC. Please dude, grab some intro tutorial on programming. Your code violates almost every single good practice and pattern ever created by mankind.

Comment: [PRAGMA table_info<table name here>](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info).

Comment: I just grab this code from the net just wanna show what im trying to do. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1) make sure the db is open

2) make sure the command is hooked up with the connection

3) make sure you are not getting any errors

4) loop through the column names

```
var cmd = new SQLiteCommand("select * from t1", db);
var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
for (var i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dr.GetName(i));
}
```

Comment: This will only get one column name thought.  He wants them all.

Comment: @Brian: well, ok i can show how to write a for loop I guess. LOL.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the answer provided by [muratgu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26224/muratgu) I created the following method:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Checks if the given table contains a column with the given name.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tableName">The table in this database to check.</param>
/// <param name="columnName">The column in the given table to look for.</param>
/// <param name="connection">The SQLiteConnection for this database.</param>
/// <returns>True if the given table contains a column with the given name.</returns>
public static bool ColumnExists(string tableName, string columnName, SQLiteConnection connection)
{
    var cmd = new SQLiteCommand($"PRAGMA table_info({tableName})", connection);
    var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())//loop through the various columns and their info
    {
        var value = dr.GetValue(1);//column 1 from the result contains the column names
        if (columnName.Equals(value))
        {
            dr.Close();
            return true;
        }
    }

    dr.Close();
    return false;
}
```