# SQLite Get columns

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
public static List<string> GetColumns(SQLiteConnection connection, string tableName)
{
        List<string> a = null;
        try
        {
            string commandString = "PRAGMA table_info('" + tableName + "');";
            SQLiteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand(commandString, new object[0]);
            command.CommandText = commandString;
            a = command.ExecuteQuery<string>();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogException(e);
        }
        return a;
    }
```

I don't know how to get the columns from the executeQuery. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should execute the query as reader : `command.ExecuteReader()`

I think your question was asked before. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284967/is-it-possible-to-get-column-name-header-in-sqlite-using-c)

---

If you are using [sqlite-net-pcl](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) you need just call `connection.GetTableInfo(tableName)`. It will give you a list of columns with their information.

Comment: Tis package (SQLite PCL) does not contain ExecuteReader method

Comment: if you mean [sqlite-net-pcl](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net), for getting column names you need to just call `connection.GetTableInfo(tableName)`